# Why is qCDebug() macro defined in the way it is?

Tags: c++, qt, coding-style

The qCDebug() macro has a simple declaration, but what are the benefits of using the "degenerate `for`-loop" instead of a simple and straightforward `if`?

```
    #define qCDebug(category, ...) \
        for (bool qt_category_enabled = category().isDebugEnabled(); qt_category_enabled; qt_category_enabled = false) \
            QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC, category().categoryName()).debug(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Modern compilers are giving the same result with optimizations higher than -O0, so that should not be the reason.

The variable `qt_category_enabled` is not used in the loop body.

There seem also to be no side-effects required for using this as a macro, such as adding another level of scops.

So, why not just

```
    #define qCDebug(category, ...) \
        if (category().isDebugEnabled()) \
            QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC, category().categoryName()).debug(__VA_ARGS__)
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the example.

```
if (condition)
  qCDebug(...);
else
  exit(0);
```

If for-loop is used, the expanded code behaves as expected.

```
if (condition)
  for (...; category().isDebugEnabled(); ...)
    QMessageLogger(...);
else
  exit(0);
```

In case of if-condition else-branch is always attached to the nearest if, and you get the expanded code

```
if (condition)
  if (category().isDebugEnabled())
    QMessageLogger(...);
  else
    exit(0);
```

See the difference?

This error can be fixed by defining the macro like

```
#define qCDebug(category, ...) \
  if (category().isDebugEnabled()) \
    QMessageLogger(QT_MESSAGELOG_FILE, QT_MESSAGELOG_LINE, QT_MESSAGELOG_FUNC, category().categoryName()).debug(__VA_ARGS__); \
  else (void)0
```

Why not done this, is an opinion based question.

Comment: The solution with `else (void)0` is not done because that macro is supposed to be used in the following way: 
`qCDebug(cat) << "my log message";`
so the macro should end with an "opened" QMessageLogger object.